# How to lock screen besides pressing Nexus S right side power button

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-nexus-s

I was wondering, besides locking screen by pressing Nexus S right side power hardware button, is there any way to lock screen, using software button press instead of hardware?

Comment: Such as a widget on the home screen?

Comment: why?

Comment: @Lie: I guess that can be useful... Maybe in case the button is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many widgets available on the [Android Market](https://market.android.com/search?q=screen%20lock%20widget&c=apps&price=1&so=1) that provide this functionality.

If you are running a custom ROM on your Nexus S (e.g. CyanogenMod) you might already have this feature within the Notification power widget.  Go to `Menu -> Settings -> CyanogenMod Settings -> Interface -> Notification power widget -> Widget buttons` and enable the `Go to sleep` button (also enable the widget itself in the previous screen.)  Now when you pull down the notification bar you can tap the "zzZ" button to lock the phone.

Comment: I don't have custom ROM yet. Out of curiosity, how do you unlock the phone after you press "zzZ" button?

Comment: You can unlock it normally, with the Power button.  CyanogenMod ROM also has a feature that allows you to unlock with other hardware buttons as well, such as the trackball on Nexus One, or Volume keys on Nexus S.