# Android widget to lock my android phone

Tags: samsung, app-widgets

Is there any android widget which allows me to lock my phone?
The 'power' button on my android phone is broken? I can't use that to lock my phone screen.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no.

[Extended Answer]
This would require the use of [PowerManager.gotoSleep(long time)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#goToSleep%28long%29), and the use of that method requires the [android.permission.DEVICE_POWER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#DEVICE_POWER) permission. DEVICE_POWER is only available to applications signed as system applications. Only applications that ship with the device and signed by the manufacture would be allowed to use the method.

Comment: I read http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9826/how-to-lock-screen-besides-pressing-nexus-s-right-side-power-button and I am able to find and install a Lock Screen Widget. Why a Widget can do that despite what you said?

Comment: a "lock screen widget" does not actually lock the device. the lock screen cannot be replaced (currently) in android. These applications attempt to override the lock screens. they are nothing more then applications that have no title bar. I have yet to find one that works without any lag when turning the device back on. If you feel that that these fit your needs, then great, but they do not actually lock the device.

Comment: @RyanConrad +1. You are right. I have tested such widget apps and they do lag. So its better not to have such wdgets.